# PHP session data getting lost in between moving from one page to other

Tags: php, session

I have a very strange problem my sessions variables were working correctly on localhost and on the live server. After some time my session variables started becoming empty. I was able to display their values, but now the session variables are showing up as empty, the code below shows my two pages with the issue.

```
include 'config.php';
include 'database.php';
ob_start();
session_id("oneway");
session_start();

elseif (isset($_POST['airport_way'])) {
  $_SESSION["name"] = $_POST['name'];
    $_SESSION["email"] = $_POST['email'];
      $_SESSION["phone"] = $_POST['phone'];

      if (isset($_POST['airport_p'])) {
        $_SESSION['convo']=$_POST['airport_p'];
      }



$_SESSION['airport']=$_POST['airport'];
$_SESSION['date']=$_POST['date_airport'];
$_SESSION['time']=$_POST['time_airport'];
header('Location: airport.php');


}
```

**now in airport.php I have**

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'config.php';
include 'database.php';
?>
<h4>Type Of Journey Airport:<?php echo $_SESSION['convo']; ?></h4>
```

Comment: Maybe you're missing a `session_start()`?  Maybe you're over-writing the values somewhere?  Maybe you're referencing the wrong values?  Maybe something else?  Actually looking at the code would be a good first step.

Comment: Share complete information with code to get help.

Comment: it was working all fine sometimes back,suddenly  empty values started getting displayed ,I am getting no errors !!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start your session after the inclusion of your files:

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
include 'database.php';

// start session here
session_start();

?>
...
```

That should work